# Screening procedure in an iterative qubit coupled cluster (iQCC) ansatz

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-algorithms, computational-models

The paper [Iterative Qubit Coupled Cluster approach with efficient screening of generators](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1906.11192.pdf) describes a new screening procedure for generators of the QCC ansatz.

How does one get from defining the flip indices $F(\hat{T})$ of a Pauli term $\hat{P}$:

$$F(\hat{P}) = \{j: \hat{f} ∈\hat{P}\}$$

to the partitioning of the second-quantised Hamiltonian as:

$$\hat{H}=\sum_{k}\hat{S}_{k},$$

where

$$\hat{S}_{k}=\sum_{j}\hat{C}_{j}\hat{P}_{j}$$

groups the terms with the same flip indices?

$$F(\hat{P}_{i})=F(\hat{P}_{j}),\quad ∀(\hat{P}_{i},\hat{P}_{j})  ∈ \hat{S}_{k}$$

And how is it that Pauli words possessing the same flip indices introduce an equivalence relation on the set of Hamiltonian terms?

Comment: the edit improves the answer, but it would be much better if you could make the post somewhat self-consistent, so that a reader doesn't have to read through the paper to get the basic definitions used in the question